# Is it possible to delete app/program data on OSX without deleting the app?

Tags: macos, mac, installation

I ask because I know this is possible on smartphones (executables exist fine, but all data is gone) and I was hoping it was possible here too.

Say for example I have VLC installed on OSX. I want to keep VLC, but delete all of it's data so that the program is as new, just like the similar process on smartphones.

Is this possible, or does it vary from app to app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways of doing this by hunting through preference files and such. However, over the years what I find much simpler us using a free program called [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

AppCleaner finds related preference files and Application Support folders for you. You have the option of deleting them and leaving the program intact, which essentially is like installing it as new. It should do what you're asking in most cases.